# EC2 instance allow outgoing traffic to specific websites

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-firewall

Here is the use case

1. We have multiple ec2 instances within a VPC.
2. We want to allow access certain websites related to our work only and block the rest.
3. The list is not static and we may need to add more sites based our policy.
4. Security Group - outbound rules allow traffic based on only IP not websites.

Is there any way to allow or block traffic in ec2 instance based on the websites?

Firewall may be one option, but updating rules to multiple machines might be an overhead.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an easy task. A website might contain content from multiple servers, CDNs, ad servers and even Amazon S3. There is no single way to define what is coming from "a website". As an example, a website might include an image that is served from S3. The URL for that image would be unrelated to the website.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein correct. For simplicity I can say all the website which we want to allow access hosted on same server.

Comment: You would need to control access based on IP address, not domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try blocking traffic from a single IP/IP ranges,just by doing following things:

Open your VPC dashboard.

Open the Network ACL.

Open the ACL editor and add a rule to block the traffic.

This is a reference tutorial link for the same.

[Blocking traffice in EC2](http://chopmo.dk/posts/2015/06/13/blocking-traffic-in-aws.html)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am wondering if ACL tables allows the website name instead of IP address. All the example in ACL also uses the IP address. I will try it with website address.